# Regarding Visual Force Page standard Controller tags

Tags: visualforce, custom-object, standardcontroller

Visual force Page standard Controller code:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
<apex:commandButton action="{!Cancel}" value="Back"/>
<apex:commandButton action="{!Save}" value="Save" />
```

The above code is Standard Controller Code, which contains standard commandbutton action such as cancel and save

custom object:

```
<apex:page standardController="Visit__c">
<apex:commandButton action="{!Cancel}" value="Back"/>
<apex:commandButton action="{!SaveNavigate}" value="Save">
```

The above code contains save and Navigate Option,how they are adding functionality of action called `{!SaveNavigate}` Manually in custom object.

Comment: What is your question, exactly? That second example won't work without a controller extension defined...

Comment: cancel and save command button belongs to account object,how save and navigate  action is Created customally in that custom object How?

Comment: Your examples are invalid. Every `StandardController` has the same methods, and `saveNavigate` is not one of them. The second `<apex:page>` tag should have an `extensions` attribute. Where are you getting these examples from?

Comment: or Save and Navigate is a Variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every `StandardController` has the **[same available methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_ApexPages_StandardController_methods.htm)**, and `SaveNavigate` is not one of them. In order to define such a method, you would need to **[Build a Controller Extension](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_extension.htm)**. Without specifying the `extensions` attribute on your `<apex:page>`, your included examples should fail to compile.

**Markup**

```
<apex:page standardController="MyObject__c" extensions="MyExtension">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:commandButton value="Custom" action="{!saveNavigate}" />
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Code**

```
public with sharing class MyExtension
{
    public MyExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
    {
        // any necessary constructor logic
    }
    public PageReference saveNavigate()
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```